# Does $A\setminus B$ and $A\setminus(A\cap B)$ mean the same thing?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

Is it right to say that $A\setminus B$ is the same as $A\setminus(A\cap B)$?

Comment: Yes and no. They are equal but not the same.

Comment: Different expressions, equal values. Different meaning, same result.

Answer (score 1):

It's true that $A \setminus B = A \setminus (A \cap B)$. 
\begin{align*}
A \setminus (A \cap B) &= A \cap (A \cap B)^c \\
&= A \cap (A^c \cup B^c) \\
&= (A \cap A^c) \cup (A \cap B^c) \\
&= \emptyset \cup (A \setminus B) \\
&= A \setminus B
\end{align*}